# Find comma in quotes with regex and replace with HTML equiv

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm looking in a string such as:

```
"Hello, Tim"

Land of the free, and home of the brave
```

And I need it to become:

```
"Hello&#44; Tim"

Land of the free, and home of the brave
```

This I thought was simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Im importing a corrupt CSV with 1000s of entries via AJAX, so I just need to convert commas INSIDE of double quotes.

How would I go about do this with JavaScript? I can't figure it out. I tried

Comment: You sure you want to use javascript to do this? Why not fix the data outside of the import step, then import the fixed version?

Comment: By the way, commas in quotes is perfectly valid in CSV.

Comment: They're valid, but making JSON break

Comment: Still weird. Your JSON library should be able to handle string literal... Ho well. Just pointing out obvious things `:)`

Comment: I'm trying to parse with CSVtoArray() from: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm and my dataset is: https://gist.github.com/1023560 It's breaking every time it hits like <a href="..."> and splits the " there so the array has just `<a href="` Any help?

Comment: @Spencer we could use something else, but it's just for playing with right now for a prototype. We tried MySQL but the data was borked just like the JSON/Array with JavaScript. Im just trying to get the data fixed anyway i can :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '"Hello, Tim"\n\
\n\
Land of the free, and home of the brave';

str
.split('"')
.map(function(v,i){ return i%2===0 ? v : v.replace(',','&#44;'); })
.join('"');
```

[Check MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for an implementation of `map()` for non-supporting browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier with a [callback function to `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
s = s.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(g0){return g0.replace(/,/g,'&#44;');});
```

At the first step we find all quotes, and replace just the commas in them.

You can even allow escaping quotes:

- CSV style (with two double quotes) - `/"([^"]|"")*"/g`
- String literal style - `/"([^"\\]|\\.)*"/g`

Comment: This still doesn't take into account escaped quotes between string, we can complicate it further when needed.

Comment: I think I'm also having issues with double quotes in the double quotes PLUS double quotes for HTML. For example: `"<a href="example">"Example"</a>"`. It's breaking and returning `<a href="` just like that. Any ideas?

Comment: @Oscar - There is no way of guessing from the question that this is what you're doing... The problem is a lot more complex than it appears. Can you please *update the question* with the full details, including a problematic snippet from the JSON/CSV string, with explanation of how a standard parser fails? (Oh, I see you've done that in the comments. Great!)

Comment: I think it'd be totally changing the scope of the question. Ill open a new question with more details and everything thats failing...

Answer (score 1):

With the above string as variable `html` you can use following code:

```
var m = html.match(/"[\s\S]*"/);
html = html.replace(m[0], m[0].replace(/,/g, '&#44;'));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
"Hello&#44; Tim"

Land of the free, and home of the brave
```

Answer (score 0):

`result = subject.replace(/("[^"]+?),([^"]*?")/img, "$1&#44;$2");`

This will work properly with your example, the only catch is it will not work if you have multiple `,` inside of the `"`. If you need it to work with multiple `,` inside of the `"` then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data) for a more complete way to parse CSV data with javascript.