# Javascript: Replace Comma with ### - only with in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

In the below string,

```
'This "is, "just, for", Test", ignore it. My name is "FirstName, LastName".'
```

I want to replace all Commas(,) only inside the double quotes("") with ###.

For now I only found the matching pattern for (""), but need to build the regex to replace the commas.

```
/".*?"/g
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance ;)

Expected o/p: This "is### "just### for"### Test", ignore it. My name is "FirstName### LastName".

Note: This is not dupe of "[Find comma in quotes with regex and replace with HTML equiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335264/find-comma-in-quotes-with-regex-and-replace-with-html-equiv)". Please see my expected o/p(Even I wanna replace the Comma in inner double quotes).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using a callback ...

```
var r = s.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function(v) { 
      return v.replace(/,/g, '###');
});
```

Comment: Wow great :), Could you please explain what exactly first and second replace doing?

Comment: The first replacement matches double quotes and everything in between them `v` (the matched content), the second replacement replaces all commas that are inside of the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a doubt here, to match double quotes we can use "/".*?"/g" also know, Could you please explain why you used negated class[^"], I mean why you are negotiate " inside the double quotes?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The negated class means any character except `"` one or more times. Which I used to reduce backtracking.

Comment: Thanks again. But I want to replace all commas those are inside double quotes. e.g, if we get the string like 'This "is, "just, for", Test", ignore it.'. Here I want to replace all Commas except in front of "ignore". Could you please help me out from this?

Comment: With the negated double quote combined with `+`, how does the engine know to stop at the second quote?

Comment: Hi, any luck for my question? ---  I want to replace all commas those are inside double quotes. e.g, if we get the string like 'This "is, "just, for", Test", ignore it.'. Here I want to replace all Commas except in front of "ignore". Could you please help me out from this?

Comment: Yes, don't use regex if that is the case.